# dcast from wide to long

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2

this ought to be easy but I cant find the correct way to do it.

```
jk <- data.frame(j=c("a","b","a","b"),val=c(1,3,2,1))
```

I´d like dcast to return two columns a and b with {1,2} and {3,1} respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `unstack`

```
unstack(jk, val ~ j)
```

-output

```
#  a b
#1 1 3
#2 2 1
```

---

If we use `dcast`, create a sequence column because there are duplicates for 'j'

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(jk), rowid(j) ~ j, value.var = 'val')[, j := NULL][]
```

-output

```
#  a b
#1: 1 3
#2: 2 1
```